# conda pytrends skeleton error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install [pytrends](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends) using conda.

But typing `conda skeleton pypi pytrends` gives the error `Error: Could not build recipe for pytrends. Could not find any valid urls.`

Is there a good way to install pytrends using conda?

I was hoping to go with conda first before using pip or setup.py.